# Add <span> within the <li> output of <? wp_nav_menu() ?>

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

Im currently printing out:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

Which outputs:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li class="current_page_item">Frontpage</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-2">etc</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

In my original HTML setup ive got an `<span>` within the `<li>` which looks like this:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>
        <a href="#">Menu1</a>
      </span>
    </li>
```

Any ideas on how to adjust this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the arguments `before` and `after`:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'menu_class' => 'nav-menu',
        'before' => '<span>',
        'after' => '</span>'
    )
);
```

To see how these arguments are used, look at the method `start_el()` in `Walker_Nav_Menu`:

```
    $item_output = $args->before; // 'before'
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after; //'after'
```

Comment: Hi Toscho, thanks a lot for your response. I tried what you suggested, but am not seeing any <span> in the output. Would the thought be that the "before" + "after" will automatically set the <span> within the <li>?

Comment: @user1231561 I tested it, see my update. Make sure, your have actually set a menu for that theme location.

Comment: More info at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu